# Attempting to deserialize an object using JSON.NET in Windows 10 Universal App fails with FileNotFoundException

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, json.net, windows-10

I'm using the Windows 10 Preview SDK, and attempting to port forward some code that depends on JSON.NET. It's failing with the following exception:

> {"Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime.Serialization,
>   Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e,
>   Retargetable=Yes' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find
>   the file specified.":"System.Runtime.Serialization, Version=2.0.5.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e, Retargetable=Yes"}

I can see that namespace present in the Object Browser, so I'm not sure what's missing or how to resolve this error. This seems to be blocking my app from moving over.

Comment: Weird, I got JSON.NET to work in my Win10 project. Did you import JSON.NET from nuget or via a dll?

Comment: NuGet, into a "Class Library (Windows Universal)" project type. I tried 6.0.8 and 7.0.1-beta3. Haven't tried using it directly in the application project though: I'll try that now.

Comment: No luck, I get the same error. Which version of JSON.NET are you using, and what do you have the dependency resolution behavior set to in NuGet?

Comment: 6.0.8 and Lowest. I used it on a clean Win10 project.

Comment: That worked - I think I still had a project depending on 7.0.1 when I thought I'd updated all of them to use 6.0.8. Can't mark a comment as the accepted answer, but thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug in NuGet that was fixed between RC and RTM releases. https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/454.

We might be able to ship an update on the gallery before RTM

Answer (score 6):

Current workaround:

**Use this version: 6.0.8**

Important: You have to check **ALL projects** on your solution. If any of them have a 7.0.x version, downgrade it to 6.0.8.

Hope the fix will arrive soon.

Comment: It's been to months. Is there still no fix? Is it possible to leave a link to a issue page or so here, so that users can see what's the status?

Comment: Have you tested on new SDK already? If so, on July 29th, make a clean install of Windows 10, new Visual Studio 2015 and new SDK. They'll probably fix it some days around this date, but ask Yishai if you need confirmation.

Comment: I have created a pull request for stylecop analyzers in which I have solved a reference warning by [downgrading](https://github.com/DotNetAnalyzers/StyleCopAnalyzers/issues/1345) newtonsoft. A similar problem is observed where references to framework 2.0.5.0 occur.